# How can I complete Rainbow Road (Mario Kart Wii) without falling off?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I am quite experienced in the Mario Kart series, but when I went on Rainbow Road I always came 7th to 11th. How can avoid falling off the track?

By the way, I use manual, not automatic.

Comment: There should be a ton of youtube videos. Perhaps look a couple of them and check what is different in comparison to your race?

Comment: But I played yesterday night, and I actually became worse. I kept falling off near the ramp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really boils down to your personal skill, the motion controls of the wiimote make it very susceptible to shoddy performance as it is. Mario Kart Wii supports the following alternative control schemes, all which don't use motion controls:

- Gamecube controller
- Wiimote + Nunchuck
- Classic Controller

Rainbow Road makes liberal use of turns, here your ability to drift makes the biggest difference. There are several places where you need to be able to make tight drifts, and others where you need to make wider turns.

Your setup *does* matter. Different characters and karts/bikes are going to have different characteristics. Some will be better at turns than others. For example, I personally prefer Funky Kong with the Flame Rider. Others might prefer smaller characters to maximize their handling and acceleration over top speed.

Use your mini-boosts to your advantage. Probably the single most-important thing about the mini-boost is that it straightens out your turn. Letting go of your drift means you're going to be shot in whichever direction your kart is facing, use this to your advantage. For example, in the large 8-section I use it to ensure I go straight across instead of falling into one of the holes.

Comment: I am curious with the different setups... How can you change your current one, and how does the Wiimote + Nunchuck work?

Comment: "Different setup" means you choose a different character or kart/bike. Wiimote + Nunchuck works in a similar fashion to a gamecube controller: A is your accelerate, B (right trigger) is your drift, Z (left trigger) to use items. You can find out how each control scheme works here: http://www.allgame.com/game.php?id=53215&tab=controls

Answer (score 1):

Well this track (like every track but, this one really does) requires a lot of drifting and wise use of mushrooms. Youll be drifting at every turn and sometimes even decelerating (3 times if i remember correctly). That being said, training is really all you need.

Vehicles are really of your choice. I think karts are better than bikes but bikes will be easier not to fall with.

Need more info? Ask in comment :)

Comment: I've found that karts give you more traction, while bikes give you more turning. My set-up was always either King Boo or Rosalina and the Wario Bike. I normally took first to fourth on 150cc, but I also have played a lot of Mario Kart so I have very high skill.

Comment: @Cyberson It is just Mario Kart Wii that is hard. Others are easier with just buttons to press, but here I have to use a motion sensor on the Wii remote.

Comment: @Mariofan1239 oh, so you use the tilt controls? That might make it harder. I've only used the nunchuk configuration so that might have a factor to play in that.

Comment: I firmy believe its simply harder to use motion controls. Maybe its more fun or more pleasant, that's really personal, but i think that regular controls are just more optimal and precise if you wanna win.
At least that's what i've noticed from my experience and from the ladder. Never seen anyone in the top tier using motion controls